# How does the 'delete' operator actually work behind the scenes in C++ in dynamic memory allocation (heap)?

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory, delete-operator

I am not getting how the "delete" operator is actually implemented behind the scenes in C++. For example:

```
class Node{
  int i;
  Node *left,*right;
};

int main()    {
  Node* a = new Node; // somehow the object 'a' is initialised with its data members
  delete a;
}
```

What exactly does `delete a;` do behind the scenes? Like is 
there any default destructor called upon or what? Also, as `a` contains left and right pointers, is the object `a->left` and `a->right` also deleted?
What happens at the **core machine level**?

Comment: What happens at "core machine level" is not specified as part of C++.   It varies between "core machines" (i.e. combination of hardware and operating system, if any), as well as implementation of compilers and (standard) libraries.   Any answer you get will either be generic (unspecific to any machine) or highly specific to some "core machine" but inapplicable to another.

Comment: Best assumption is that *nothing* happens.  The block is added back into the free space list, ready to be used again for the next allocation.  If the sun is shining and you got the wind in your back then that free space might grow big enough that pages can be unmapped to relieve pressure on the paging file, assuming your OS uses one.  Do have a look at the source code of the CRT you use, it will tell you what *really* happens.

Answer (score 7):

### Nomenclature

According to the C++ standard *§12.4 Destructors/p4,p6,p7,p8,p12 [class.dtor]* (**Emphasis mine**):

> <sup>4</sup> **If a class has no user-declared destructor, a
>   destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted** (8.4). An implicitly
>   declared destructor is an inline public member of its class.
>
> <sup>6</sup> **A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided**
>   and if:
>
> <sup>(6.1)</sup> — the destructor is not virtual,
>
> <sup>(6.2)</sup> — all of the direct base classes of its class have
>   trivial destructors, and
>
> <sup>(6.3)</sup> — for all of the non-static data members of its class
>   that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a
>   trivial destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is non-trivial.
>
> <sup>7</sup> **A destructor that is defaulted and not defined as
>   deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used** (3.2) or when it
>   is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.
>
> <sup>12</sup> **A destructor is invoked implicitly**
>
> <sup>(12.1)</sup> — for a constructed object with static storage
>   duration (3.7.1) at program termination (3.6.4),
>
> <sup>(12.2)</sup> — for a constructed object with thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) at thread exit,
>
> <sup>(12.3)</sup> — for a constructed object with automatic storage
>   duration (3.7.3) when the block in which an object is created exits
>   (6.7),
>
> <sup>(12.4)</sup> — for a constructed temporary object when its
>   lifetime ends (4.4, 12.2). In each case, the context of the invocation
>   is the context of the construction of the object. **A destructor is
>   also invoked implicitly through use of a delete-expression (5.3.5) for
>   a constructed object allocated by a new-expression (5.3.4); the
>   context of the invocation is the delete-expression.** [ Note: An array
>   of class type contains several subobjects for each of which the
>   destructor is invoked. — end note ] A destructor can also be invoked
>   explicitly. A destructor is potentially invoked if it is invoked or as
>   specified in 5.3.4, 12.6.2, and 15.1. A program is ill-formed if a
>   destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible
>   from the context of the invocation.

**DR;TL**

In C++ if a `class`, `struct` or `union` doesn't have a user declared destructor, then the compiler will always implicitly declare one trivial destructor for it. That is, although you haven't declared a destructor for your `Node` class the compiler is obliged by the C++ standard to declare a trivial one for you.

This implicitly declared trivial destructor will be defined once upon your class is *odr-used*. That is, when any expression anywhere in the program takes the address of or binds a reference directly to an object of your class.

Calling `delete` upon a `Node` object that was previously allocated with `new` will evoke its implicitly defined destructor and the heap storage allocated for that object by `new` will be reclaimed (i.e., freed).

Since the implicit declared destructor is trivial, any storage pointed by member pointers `left` and `right` will not be touched at all. Meaning that, if you've allocated any memory that is being pointed only by the `left` and `right` member pointers of a `Node` object. After calling delete upon this object the memory that was being pointed by member pointers `left` and `right` will be orphan (i.e., you'll have a memory leak).

### What Happens At Core Machine Level

What happens at core machine level may vary from vendor to vendor, from operating system to operating system and from machine to machine as the core behaviour of a delete expression is not specified by the C++ standard. Any compiler vendor can do anything it feels like it to (e.g., optimizations), as long as the observable behaviour conforms with the C++ standard.

More or less though, vendors are doing similar things. For example lets take into account the following piece of code:

```
class Node {
  int i;
  Node *left, *right;
};

int main() {
  Node *n = new Node;
  delete n;
}
```

The generated assembly code for the above piece of code for GCC version 6.2 compiler is:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     edi, 24
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, 24
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

In the assembly code generated for our simple example, the construction of the `n` object is represented by the code snippet below:

```
sub     rsp, 16
mov     edi, 24
call    operator new(unsigned long)
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
```

Since the object is trivially constructible the only thing the compiler does is allocation of memory for the object by calling the implicitly declared global operator `new`.

The destruction process of the object is represented by the code snippet below:

```
rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov     esi, 24
mov     rdi, rax
call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

Notice, that the destruction process is done in reverse order with respect the steps taken in the construction process. At the end the implicitly declared global operator `delete` is called to free the previously allocated memory.

In our example neither a constructor nor a destructor is called since in our case the observable behaviour of the program doesn't change if they are not called.

Now the rightfull question is where in heck `operator delete` is?

In order to preserve the nomenclaturstic style of this answer lets quote the C++ standard from `§3.7.4 Dynamic storage duration [basic.stc.dynamic]\p1, p2` (**Emphasis Mine**):

> <sup>1</sup> **Objects can be created dynamically during program
>   execution (1.9), using new-expressions (5.3.4), and destroyed using
>   delete-expressions (5.3.5). A C++ implementation provides access to,
>   and management of, dynamic storage via the global allocation functions
>   operator new and operator new[] and the global deallocation functions
>   operator delete and operator delete[].** [ Note: The non-allocating
>   forms described in 18.6.2.3 do not perform allocation or deallocation.
>   — end note ]
>
> <sup>2</sup> **The library provides default definitions for the global
>   allocation and deallocation functions.** Some global allocation and
>   deallocation functions are replaceable (18.6.2). A C++ program shall
>   provide at most one definition of a replaceable allocation or
>   deallocation function. Any such function definition replaces the
>   default version provided in the library (17.5.4.6). **The following
>   allocation and deallocation functions (18.6) are implicitly declared
>   in global scope in each translation unit of a program.**
>
> ```
> void* operator new(std::size_t); 
> void* operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t); void operator delete(void*) noexcept; 
> void operator delete(void*, std::size_t) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void*, std::size_t, std::align_val_t) noexcept;
> void* operator new[](std::size_t);
> void* operator new[](std::size_t, std::align_val_t);
> void operator delete[](void*) noexcept;
> void operator delete[](void*, std::size_t) noexcept;
> void operator delete[](void*, std::align_val_t) noexcept;
> void operator delete[](void*, std::size_t, std::align_val_t) noexcept;
> ```
>
> These implicit declarations introduce only the function names operator
>   `new`, `operator new[]`, `operator delete`, and `operator delete[]`. [
>   Note: The implicit declarations do not introduce the names `std`,
>   `std::size_t`, `std::align_val_t`, or any other names that the library
>   uses to declare these names. Thus, a new-expression, delete-expression
>   or function call that refers to one of these functions without
>   including the header  is well-formed. However, referring to std
>   or std::size_t or std::align_val_t is ill-formed unless the name has
>   been declared by including the appropriate header. — end note ]
>   Allocation and/or deallocation functions may also be declared and
>   defined for any class (12.5).

The answer is the delete operator is implicitly declared in global scope in each translation unit of your program.

Comment: I got your most of the points. Just ONE DOUBT : in your last line you said that the member pointers left or right will be orphan (i.e. we'll get a memory leak), what do you exactly mean by that ? Does it mean that after deleting current object 'a' , I won't be able to access Nodes via a->left or a->right ??

Comment: @ShivamPandey: After `delete a`, it's undefined behaviour to access `a->left` or `a->right`. And if `a->left` and `a->right` happened to be the **only** two pointers to those two Node objects, then you have a memory leak, yes. C++ doesn't care that no pointers point to the two Node objects anymore. It does not have garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not definied by standard, so this question can't really be answered because multiple implementations of standard library can implement this stuff as they please.

And no, `*left` and `*right` are not deleted (aka it doesn't do something like `delete left`, it just erases them from memory). Just like `new Node` doesn't allocate additional memory to set `*left` / `*right`.

You haven't explicitly defined ctor or dtor, so nothing speciall will happen. However if you will define constructor / destructor those will be called by `new` & `delete`.
//edit: Ofc they're called now, without user-defined ctor/dtor, but don't do anything useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

c++ calls a default **destructor** when the scope of the object ends

The purpose of **delete** is to return the memory (i.e free the memory) so it is available to the computer for use

Basically when you allocate memory during runtime using **New** or something else it is your responsibility to free that memory after the Task is done 
If you don't free memory and the pointer / object dies then the memory you used is wasted and the computer can not use that memory and this is called memory leak.

If you lose too much memory through memory leak , your heap/free store won't have enough memory to run your Operating System and eventually you'll have to reboot the system

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly does `delete a;` do behind the scenes?

It *probably* just goes to the location of the free store where the object pointed to by `a` is stored, and marks the memory as available for future allocations. *Perhaps* the memory is additionally zeroed out or otherwise tampered with if you have told your compiler to create a debug-friendly version of the program.

Whatever the compiler does, the only *guaranteed* effect is that a subsequent `delete a` or an attempt to dereference `a` causes undefined behaviour.

C++ defines a language, not an implementation.

Applying the *as-if rule*, perhaps nothing happens at all because compiler optimisation has shown that this piece of code isn't needed to create the required observable behaviour of the program.

> Like is there any default destructor called upon or what?

If you don't write a destructor, then the compiler will insert a `public` one automatically.

> Also, as `a` contains `left` and `right` pointers, is the object `a->left` and `a->right` also deleted?

Careful with your wording. `a->left` and `a->right` *are* two objects, just like `a->i`. C++ uses the word "object" much more liberally than certain other programming languages.

All three objects are deleted, yes. However, `a->left` and `a->right` each may or may not point to some other `Node` object. Those other `Node` objects are not deleted.

After all, **why should they?** Who says that those two other `Node` objects are only pointed to by `a->left` and `a->right`? Consider this:

```
struct Node{
  int i;
  Node *left,*right;
};

int main()    {
  Node* a = new Node;
  Node l;
  Node r;
  a->left = &l;
  a->right = &r;
  delete a;
}
```

If `delete` worked in a transitive way, then your code would attempt to delete the local objects `l` and `r` which aren't even allocated on the free store; this would be a disaster with undefined behaviour.

> What happens at the core machine level?

C++ doesn't say what happens at the core machine level.