# Will array a get de-allocated in this case?

Tags: c++

Does re-locating an array pointer affect the working of delete operator?

Case (1)

```
int main(){
   int *a = new int[5];
   a++; a--;
   delete[] a;
   return 0;
 }
```

Case (2)

```
int main(){
   int *a = new int[5];
   a++;
   delete[] a;
   return 0;
 }
```

Case (3)

```
int main(){
   int *a = new int[5];
   a++;
   delete[] a;
   a--;
   delete[] a;
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You are just incrementing and decrementing a pointer. You are not "relocating" anything. Changing the value of a pointer doesn't in any way affect what it points to (or used to point to). A pointer is just a variable pointing to something else - it's like a sign saying "it's over there", when you change the sign that doesn't change what's "over there".

Comment: Thanks for the info..I have updated the question's description.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow Please don't change the question after getting an answer.

Comment: Should I ask a new question? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Next time - yes. Or you can ask some additional questions in the comments.

Comment: (1) yes; (2) UB; (3) UB on the 1st `delete` so the later lines are not relevant

Comment: Case 2 & 3 are both Undefined Behaviour. You are not `delete`ing what you `new`ed.

Comment: Can we say that the first part of the case 3 is UB and the second part de-allocates the array?

Comment: __Undefined behavior__: _"Renders the entire program meaningless if certain rules of the language are violated"_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub  Also __Undefined behavior can result in time travel__ source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=633

Comment: @RichardCritten So can UB can lead to even more memory leaks if the program is long enough?

Comment: Like I haven't noticed nothing of that sort happening till date..That's why I was a bit curious.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow UB means you no longer have a program that you can reason about.  All bets are off and all analysis is void.  Fix the UB and we are back in the land of logic

Comment: @RichardCritten Hmm...Undefined Behavior and Infinity..Anyways thanks for the info :)

Comment: UB bugs are of the form "the program is not doing what I wanted, and not doing what I've asked".  Well-behaved bugs are "the program is not doing what I wanted, but is doing what I've asked."  The former are hard, and worth eliminating, and turning up the compiler's warning level can help the compiler help you (or other static analysis tools like Coverity).  The latter can be reasoned about.

Comment: Further reading on UB: Part 1/3:  http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html and another Part 1/3 https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: So undefined behavior remains fixed for a given code and compiler?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow you are trying to reason about UB again.  Once are in UB land a butterfly taking off around the world from you can change the behaviour of your program.

Comment: I can understand what your trying to say. I'll read through all the links you have shared. Thank you for your time and willingness to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: [Cases 2 and 3] it is UNDEFINED. The operator is likely to search for the object to de-allocate based on it address but will fail to find it. Don't try this at home ;)

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325978/how-does-the-delete-operator-actually-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c-in-dynamic).

Original answer to original question --- for case 1 ---:
your code does not really relocate the array; eventually the address passed to delete[] operator is the same address allocated by (and returned by new[] operator. Overall, the functionality of delete[] here is safe and defined.

Comment: So what would have happen if I would have called not decremented a?

Comment: I have updated the question description, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: it is UNDEFINED. The operator is likely to search for the object to de-allocate based on it address but will fail to find it. Don't try this at home ;)

Comment: I suggest clarifying which cases out of the 3 are UB.

Comment: What does UB mean @HolyBlackCat?

Comment: UB is a commonly used shortcut by C programmers that stands for "undefined behavior".